# row wise count the number of the words in a review text in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, text-mining

**I want to count the number of words in each row:**

```
Review_ID   Review_Date   Review_Content   Listing_Title   Star   Hotel_Name
 1          1/25/2016     I booked both the Crosby and Four Seasons but decided to cancel the Four Seasons closer to the arrival date based on reviews. Glad I did. The Crosby is an outstanding hotel. The rooms are immaculate and luxurious, with real attention to detail and none of the bland furnishings you find in even the top chain hotels. Staff on the whole were extremely attentive and seemed to enjoy being there. Breakfast was superb and facilities at ground level gave an intimate and exclusive feel to the hotel. It's a fairly expensive place to stay but is one of those hotels where you feel you're getting what you pay for, helped by an excellent location. Hope to be back!   Outstanding  5  Crosby Street Hotel
 2          1/18/2016     We've stayed many times at the Crosby Street Hotel and always have an incredible, flawless experience! The staff couldn't be more accommodating, the housekeeping is immaculate, the location's awesome and the rooms are the coolest combination of luxury and chic. During our most recent trip over The New Years holiday, we stayed in the stunning Crosby Suite which has the most extraordinary, gorgeous decor. The Crosby remains our absolute favorite in NYC. Can't wait to return!   Always perfect!   5   Crosby Street Hotel
```

**I was thinking something like:**

```
WordFreqRowWise %>% 
rowwise() %>%
summarise(n = n())
```

**To get the results something like..**

```
Review_ID   Review_Content   total_Words   Min_occrd_word   Max      Average
   1            ....            230           great: 1      the: 25  total_unique/total_words in the row
```

**But do not have idea, how can I do it....**

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method in base R using `strsplit` and `sapply`. Let's say the data is stored in a data.frame df and the reviews are stored in the variable Review_Content

```
# break up the strings in each row by " "
temp <- strsplit(df$Review_Content, split=" ")

# count the number of words as the length of the vectors
df$wordCount <- sapply(temp, length)
```

In this instance, `sapply` will return a vector of the counts for each row.

Since the word count is now an object, you can perform analysis you want on it. Here are some examples:

- summarize the distribution of word counts: `summary(df$wordCount)`
- maximum word count: `max(df$wordCount)`
- mean word count: `mean(df$wordCount)`
- range of word counts: `range(df$wordCount)`
- interquartile range of word counts: `IQR(df$wordCount)`

Comment: word count is ok. thanks @lmo but what about minimum, maximum and average word count??  Should I try `sapply(temp, max)`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to **@lmo**'s answer above..

**Below code will generate a dataframe that consists of all the words, row-wise, and their frequencies:**

```
 temp2 <- data.frame()
 for (i in 1:length(temp)){
    temp1 <- as.data.frame(table(temp[[i]]))
    temp1$ID <- paste0("Row_", i)
    temp2 <- rbind(temp2, temp1)
    temp1 <- NULL
  }
```